# "Sleep" option is not available on Win 8.1 pro

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep

I have a `microsoft surface pro 3` tablet, suddenly I found that "Sleep" option is gone as you can see the below pictures, I googled about the problem but I couldn't find any useful solution.

ps. My windows is updated to all updates.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try the item at the top of the dialog, **Change settings that are currently unavailable**?

Comment: Yes, it will only enable the below checboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,
When `Hyper-V` is enabled the sleep option won't show up.
To disable `Hyper-V` follow these instructions

1. Open Windows Features.
2. Expand the Hyper-V sub-section

[image]

3. To Disable Hyper-V

   Uncheck Hyper-V, click/tap on OK, and go to step 4 below.
4. Restart the computer when prompted.